# Processing large amount of data in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I am quite new in developing applications in laravel. I am retrieving 1000+ records from 2 db tables (using join) and displaying in a view. It takes a very long time to retrieve and display the data in a view.

I came across this chuck command in Laravel, but don't really seem to understand how to use it in passing data to the view. https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions

Any advice on how to go about it will really be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/pagination

Comment: You probably don't want to show thousands of records at once in a view. Roman's pagination link should be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you process large amount of data, creating **Eloquent's models** from the raw data you get from the database adds a lot of overhead to the processing time.

Instead of fetching model objects

```
$records = Record::all();
foreach ($records as $record) {
  // your logic here
}
```

try to fetch raw data directly:

```
DB::table('records')->get();
foreach ($records as $record) {
  // your logic here
}
```

If you don't need all the data from the table, you can pass the list of columns you want to fetch to the **get()** method:

```
DB::table('records')->get(['id', 'name']);
```